# How to revert to last commit after rebasing commit from child of child branch to parent branch?

Tags: git, rebase

I have three branches (local) called **dev**, **bugfix**, **fix_1**.
I created **dev** branch from **master** branch
then did 3 commits and checkout to new branch called **bugfix**.
I then did did 3 commits in **bugfix** branch and checkout to new branch called **fix_1** and did one commit in it.

I wanted to rebase the fixcommit from **fix_1** branch onto **dev** branch tip
but after rebasing all commits from **bugfix** branch also rebased on **dev** branch .

Below was the state of my branches before rebasing.

**STATE** **1** :

```
dev --A--B--C  
             |
             |
bugfix       x--y--z
                   |
                   |
fix_1               fixcommit
```

Below is the state of my branches after rebasing.

**STATE** **2** :

```
dev --A--B--C--x--y--z--fixcommit
             |
             |
bugfix       x--y--z
                   |
                   |
fix_1               fixcommit
```

I want to revert to the

**THIS** **STATE** :

```
dev --A--B--C--fixcommit 
             |
             |
bugfix       x--y--z
                   |
                   |
fix_1               fixcommit
```

then ,

**THIS** **STATE** :

```
dev --A--B--C--fixcommit 
                       |
                       |
bugfix                 x--y--z
```

Comment: Just do an interactive rebase going far enough and reorder the commits as you want them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are in **STATE 2**:

```
dev --A--B--C--x--y--z--fixcommit
             |
             |
bugfix       x--y--z
                   |
                   |
fix_1               fixcommit
```

you can use `git checkout dev; git reset --hard C` to get back to your **initial state**.
In the next step, use

```
git rebase --onto dev bugfix fix_1
git checkout dev
git merge --ff-only fix_1
```

in order to get to:

```
dev --A--B--C--fixcommit 
             |
             |
bugfix       x--y--z
```

In detail, this will do the following:

1. `git rebase --onto dev bugfix fix_1` will switch to branch `fix_1`, take all commits applied to this branch starting from (after) `bugfix` and applies them onto the branch `dev` in the same order
2. `git checkout dev` switches to the branch `dev`
3. `git merge --ff-only fix_1` will merge `fix_1` into `dev` by updating the branch pointer of `dev` to match the branch pointer of `fix_1`

Finally, execute `git checkout bugfix; git rebase dev` in order to get to your desired state

```
dev --A--B--C--fixcommit 
                       |
                       |
bugfix                 x--y--z
```

Comment: Thank you !!! this worked as intended and explained.
It would be great if you explain what it does under-the-hood

`git rebase --onto dev bugfix fix_1  
git checkout dev
git merge --ff-only fix_1`

Comment: @au7au7 Explanation added. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! ,I understood what you explained .